# Reorder string characters in Swift

Tags: string, swift, indexing, integer, character

So, let's say I have a String that is: "abc" and I want to change each character position so that I can have "cab" and later "bca". I want the character at index 0 to move to 1, the one on index 1 to move to 2 and the one in index 2 to 0.

What do I have in Swift to do this? Also, let's say instead of letters I had numbers. Is there any easier way to do it with integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 2:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollectionType where Index : BidirectionalIndexType {
  mutating func cycleAround() {
    insert(removeLast(&self), atIndex: startIndex)
  }
}

var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4]

ar.cycleAround() // [4, 1, 2, 3]

var letts = "abc".characters
letts.cycleAround()
String(letts) // "cab"
```

Swift 1:

```
func cycleAround<C : RangeReplaceableCollectionType where C.Index : BidirectionalIndexType>(inout col: C) {
  col.insert(removeLast(&col), atIndex: col.startIndex)
}

var word = "abc"

cycleAround(&word) // "cab"
```

Comment: The OP wants the last character to move to the beginning, not the first character to move to the end.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Swift Algorithms package](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms) there is a [`rotate`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Rotate.md) command

```
import Algorithms

let string = "abcde"
var stringArray = Array(string)
for _ in 0..<stringArray.count {
    stringArray.rotate(toStartAt: 1)
    print(String(stringArray))
}
```

Result:

```
bcdea
cdeab
deabc
eabcd
abcde
```

Answer (score -1):

### Swift 5.7.2

I had an issue where I needed to standardize an inventory number from different sources.  Some sources would place an alpha character before the number part of the unit code and others would append the alpha character to the end of the numeric portion of the unit code.  The format I needed was the character has to appear before the number.

I first have to break down the string into its individual string elements because the unit code uses dashes, but once that was done it was really simple.

I wanted this to be native to Swift without any additional frameworks or packages.

### Method:

```
func swapEndLetter(string: String) -> String {
    var string = string
    guard let letter = string.last?.isLetter else { return string }
    if letter {
        return "\(string.remove(at: string.index(before: string.endIndex)))\(string)"
    }
    return string
}
```

### Usage:

```
var unitCode = "unit-code-1102a"
var split = unitCode.components(separatedBy: "-") // ["unit", "code", "1102a"]
split[split.count-1] = swapEndLetter(string: String(split[split.count-1])) //
unitCode = split.joined(separator: "-") // "unit-code-a1102"
```